# cant hide link with z-index

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, z-index

I have a hyperlink positioned absolutely in the bottom right, but I don't want it visible when the view gets to the section it's linking to. My first thought was to use a Z-Index, but something is off.

HTML:

```
 <div class="gallery">
 </div>    
 <a href="#info">Details</a>
 <div name="info" class="textblock">
 </div>
```

---

css:

```
    #details{
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 00px;
        right: 0px;
        z-index:0;
    }

    .textblock{
        z-index:50;
    }
```

If you'd like to see it in real time, its right [here](http://www.overlandparkphotographer.com/wedding-photographer-in-overland-park-kansas-city/#details). My stylesheet is at the bottom of the list I believe wordpress named it "inline style sheet #11" I'm fully aware the gallery is garbage, I haven't swapped out with the 'photo-gallery' nor updated the photos for that matter.

Comment: You want it hidden when the user scrolls to the bottom of your site? I think there might be a typo in your question so I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: oops, yes my sentance must have gotten cut off at some point. That is my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixes the issue:

```
.textblock {
    position: relative;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. The higher the `z-index`number, the higher a layer ^^

Also one cannot use z-index on non-positioned objects.

```
#details{
        position: fixed;
         bottom: 00px;
          right: 0px;
           z-index:51;
    }

    .textblock{
      position: Relative
        z-index:50;
    }
```